# MongoDB aggregate Functionalities

Tags: mongodb

I have documents like:

```
Name    |     lastname      |     age   |    code  |  value
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+--------
aaaaa   |     zzzzzzzzz     |     10    |    1     |   11
bbbb    |     eeeeeeeee     |     20    |    2     |   22
aaaaa   |     zzzzzzzzzzz   |     10    |    3     |   null
dddd    |     nnnnnnnn      |     20    |    4     |   null
aaaaa   |     zzzzzzzzzzz   |     10    |    5     |   null
bbbb    |     eeeeeeeee     |     20    |    6     |   null
aaaaa   |     zzzzzzzzzzz   |     10    |    7     |   77
```

Using MongoDB, I am looking for a request giving that result:

1. detect those with a null value
2. group them (just `null` value) and write all their code in one field: `all_code`;
3. detect if there are other similar with a value not null and group them with those of point 2 and put all those values in a new `field=all_value`.

Therefore, it will be like:

```
 Name   |     lastname     |     age    |    all_code    |  all_values
--------+------------------+------------+----------------+------------
aaaaa   |     zzzzzzzzz    |     10     |    3 , 5       |   11,77
bbbb    |     eeeeeeeee    |     20     |    6           |   22
dddd    |     nnnnnnnn     |     20     |    4           |   null
```

I have tried this:

```
db.information.aggregate([
    {$group: 
      {
      _id:{
            name : "$name",
            lastename: "$lastename",
            age: "$age"
          },
      total:{$sum: 1},
      all_code:{ $addToSet: "$code" },
      all_values:{ $addToSet: "$value" }}},
    { $project: 
      {
    "name": 1,
    "lastename":1,
    "age":1,
    "all_code":1,
    "all_values":1,
    "total":1
    }},
    { $sort:{"total":-1}}
      ])
```

but the problem is with the `all_code` column witch has to display only codes where `value = null`, and value for those who already have value.

Comment: I believe you want a $match stage before your other aggregate stages.  {$value: null}

Comment: yes exactly, 
1. to group and count those with value null;
2.detect for each  gpe the values of thos who match but with values not null.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think this will work.  I'm not certain, and it seems like too simple an answer, but in Mongo I believe you want to split the {$group} and {$match} stages, so you just add a {$match} stage before the {$group}.  If you're coming from an SQL environment this can be confusing, but them's the breaks. In the end, it's in some ways a more flexible and powerful result, in my opinion.  Regardless, this is what I think may solve your problem:

```
db.information.aggregate([
{ $group: 
  {
  _id: {
        name : "$name",
        lastename: "$lastename",
        age: "$age"
      },
  total: {$sum: 1},
  all_code: { $addToSet: "$code" },
  all_values: {"$cond" : [{"$eq": [null, "$value"]} , null, {$addToSet: "$value"} }},
{ $project: 
  {
"name": 1,
"lastename":1,
"age":1,
"all_code":1,
"all_values":1,
"total":1
}},
{ $sort:{"total":-1}}
  ])
```

Comment: Ah, of course.  And here I thought it was such a simple question.  You're going to need quite a bit of code to make this work. I'll start working on it.

Comment: Okay, so, I think the conditional I've added MIGHT fix the issue.  I'll look into it more deeply tomorrow morning, but for the moment try this.

Comment: I've been buried in work for the last three days, sorry.  Uh....  Have you looked into the 'ifNull' aggregation operator?  That might combine with the $addToSet to give you what you need.  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/

Comment: hello @DylanBrams , even that one, it's not working :

db.information.aggregate([
{ $group: 

  {
  _id: {
        name : "$name",
        lastename: "$lastename",
        age: "$age"
      },
  all_values: {"$cond" : [{"$ne": [ "$value",null]}, {$addToSet: "$value"} , null }},
  all_code  : {"$cond" : [{"$eq": ["$value",null]} , {$addToSet: "$code"} , null }},
  total: {$sum: 1}
{ $project: 
  {
"name": 1,
"lastename":1,
"age":1,
"all_code":1,
"all_values":1,
"total":1
}},
{ $sort:{"total":-1}}
  ])

Comment: i've alos tried this: 
  total: {$sum: 1},
  all_code: { $addToSet: "$code" },
  all_values: { $addToSet: "$values" },
  all_values: {"$cond" : [{"$in": [null, "$all_value"]} ,$all_value, "nothing"} }},